# How to split string in clojure on number and convert it to map

Tags: clojure

I have a string `school_name_1_class_2_city_name_3` want to split it to `{school_name: 1, class:2, city_name: 3}` in clojure I tried this code which didn't work

```
(def s "key_name_1_key_name_2")
(->> s
     (re-seq #"(\w+)_(\d+)_")
     (map (fn [[_ k v]] [(keyword k) (Integer/parseInt v)]))
     (into {}))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the ungreedy version of regex.

Try using `#"(\w+?)_(\d+)_?"` instead.

```
user=> (->> s (re-seq #"(\w+?)_(\d+)_?"))
(["key_name_1_" "key_name" "1"] ["key_name_2" "key_name" "2"])
```

Comment: if I have negative numbers this expression fails , If I want to convert this string "key_name_1_key_name_-2" it ignores negative numbers, I updated regex to this #"(\w+?)_-?(\d+)_?" but this is converting negative numbers to positive numbers , any suggestion to retain sign

Comment: This expression solved it "(\w+?)_([+-]?\d+)_?

Answer (score 2):

When faced with a problem, just break it down and solve one small step at a time.  Using `let-spy-pretty` from [the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo) allows us to see each step of the transformation:

```clj
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require [clojure.string :as str]))

(defn str->keymap
  [s]
  (let-spy-pretty
    [str1 (re-seq #"([a-zA-Z_]+|[0-9]+)" s)
     seq1 (mapv first str1)
     seq2 (mapv #(str/replace % #"^_+" "") seq1)
     seq3 (mapv #(str/replace % #"_+$" "") seq2)
     map1 (apply hash-map seq3)
     map2 (tupelo.core/map-keys map1 #(keyword %) )
     map3 (tupelo.core/map-vals map2 #(Long/parseLong %) )]
    map3))

(dotest
  (is= (str->keymap "school_name_1_class_2_city_name_3")
    {:city_name 3, :class 2, :school_name 1}))
```

with result

```sh
------------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.3    Java 11.0.11
------------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core
str1 => 
(["school_name_" "school_name_"]
 ["1" "1"]
 ["_class_" "_class_"]
 ["2" "2"]
 ["_city_name_" "_city_name_"]
 ["3" "3"])
seq1 => 
["school_name_" "1" "_class_" "2" "_city_name_" "3"]
seq2 => 
["school_name_" "1" "class_" "2" "city_name_" "3"]
seq3 => 
["school_name" "1" "class" "2" "city_name" "3"]
map1 => 
{"city_name" "3", "class" "2", "school_name" "1"}
map2 => 
{:city_name "3", :class "2", :school_name "1"}
map3 => 
{:city_name 3, :class 2, :school_name 1}

Ran 2 tests containing 1 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.

Passed all tests
```

Once you understand the steps and everything is working, just replace `let-spy-pretty` with `let` and continue on!

This was build using [my favorite template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template).

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
(require '[clojure.string :as str])

(def s "school_name_1_class_2_city_name_3")
```

Following the accepted answer:

```
(->> s (re-seq #"(.*?)_(\d+)_?") 
       (map rest) ;; take only the rest of each element 
       (map (fn [[k v]] [k (Integer. v)])) ;; transform second as integer
       (into {})) ;; make a hash-map out of all this
```

Or:

```
(apply hash-map ;; the entire thing as a hash-map
       (interleave (str/split s #"_(\d+)(_|$)") ;; capture the names 
                   (map #(Integer. (second %))  ;; convert to int
                         (re-seq #"(?<=_)(\d+)(?=(_|$))" s)))) ;; capture the integers
```

or:

```
(zipmap
  (str/split s #"_(\d+)(_|$)")   ;; extract names
  (->> (re-seq #"_(\d+)(_|$)" s) ;; extract values
       (map second)              ;; by taking only second matched groups
       (map #(Integer. %))))     ;; and converting them to integers
```

- `str/split` leaves out the matched parts
- `re-seq`    returns only the matched parts
- `(_|$)` ensures that the number is followed by a `_` or is at an end position

The least verbose (where `(_|$)` could be replaced by `_?`:

```
(->> (re-seq #"(.*?)_(\d+)(_|$)" s)        ;; capture key vals 
     (map (fn [[_ k v]] [k (Integer. v)])) ;; reorder coercing values to int
     (into {}))                            ;; to hash-map
```